# Finding infimum of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the inf(x+1/x) for x>0. 
My doubt is:- we know that inf(A+B)= inf(A)+ inf(B)
Therefore,
                   inf(x+1/x)= inf(x) + inf(1/x)
                                     = 0+ 0= 0
But, from plotting graph of (x+1/x) for x>0 we get, infimum 2 at x=1. 
I feel that there is something that i haven't taken care of in this statement that inf(A+B) = inf(A)+inf(B) but I can't understand what.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ And can you carefully state what exactly your $A$ and $B$ are?

Comment: A and B are any two sets that are bounded below

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.

Comment: I think you mean$$A+B=\{a+b:a\in A\land b\in B\}$$which is not the same as $$\{x+\frac1x:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$in this case, so this theorem cannot be applied.

Comment: $$\left\{x+\frac{1}{x} : x > 0\right\} \neq \{x : x > 0\} + \left\{\frac{1}{x} : x > 0\right\} = \left\{x + \frac{1}{y} : x,y > 0\right\}$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring (for the OP) Note that the last set is $(0,\infty)$ but the first set is $[2,\infty)$

Comment: Okay..thank you so much. I understood my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the obvious that the $A,B$ in your workings are the sets

$$A = \{x \mid  x \in \Bbb R, x > 0 \} \;\;\;\;\; B = \{ 1/x \mid  x \in \Bbb R, x > 0 \}$$

When stating the property that $\inf(P+Q) = \inf(P) + \inf(Q)$ for sets $P,Q$, this is not immediately clear what "$P+Q$" refers to. It refers to this:

$$P+Q = \{ p+q \mid p\in P, q\in Q\}$$

Bear in mind what this really means - in words, it means all of the possible ways to sum pairs of elements, one from one set, and one from the other. This is slightly more general than what you're trying to get.

For example, obviously $2 \in A, 1/2 \in B$. Thus, $2+1/2 = 5/2 \in A+B$.

Similarly, $3 \in A, 1/4 \in B$ and thus $3+1/4 = 13/4 \in A+B$.

Another particularly enlightening example. $1/10 \in A$ **and** $1/10 \in B$. However, $1/10 + 1/10 = 1/5 \in A+B$, but clearly there is no point on the graph of $f(x) = x+1/x$ which attains that value:

[image]

The issue is that you cannot naively say $A+B$ gives you the result you want. Your function wants the $x$ and $1/x$ to take in the same input $x$, when $A+B$ just takes every possible sum regardless of whether the $x$'s are the same or not.

---

In that light, I think it's a bit much to hope for the use of that property in that exercise. My recommendation would be the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

($a,b$ are assumed nonnegative reals, and equality if and only if $a=b$.) Let $a=x, b=1/x$, and you'll be able to show that $x + 1/x \ge 2$. Equality is obtained at $x=1$, which you can show through finding $f(1)$ or letting $a=b$ ($x=1/x$), giving the desired result.

I imagine calculus could also be used but if this is for a real analysis course that might not be "fair game" from the instructor's viewpoint. It's a typical "find the minimum" problem if you can use it though.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the infimum of $x$ and $1/x$ separately, and then adding them, is not the same as taking the infimum of $x+1/x$ (for $x\gt0$).

The first,  as you noted, gives $0$;  the second $2$.

(This is because in the first case *different* values of $x$ are allowed;  that is you are actually minimizing $x+1/y$, for $x,y\gt0$. )